# FIR input frequencies

Tags: fir

I'm looking at this question with answers in my book and I don't understand one part of it. It works out the input frequencies shown at the bottom. Can someone tell me how they are getting they input frequencies? Where are they coming from?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is homework stuff, so our question to you is what have you tried to solve this? Did you ask your teacher for help? Other students? Have you done any of these equations so far?

Comment: I've did many questions myself. I've also did this question right up until I get to the input frequencies, but I'm not seeing how to go about getting the input frequencies. I'm not really asking a lot here, I'm just confused on one part out of 10 other questions...

Comment: What are the next few lines cut off the bottom of your image?

Comment: I edited the OP to show the full answer. I understand it all, I just want to know where they are getting the input frequencies from. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The input frequencies are a free choice by the question setter, in order to explore what the filter is doing.

It would have been equally as valid for the question to say `the input frequencies to the system are w_k = {0, 1, 4}`. Obviously with different input frequencies, the filter response would be different. Hint, often specific input frequencies are chosen that hit 'interesting' features of filters, or where particular factors cancel out nicely.